# What is the estimate coefficient when design matrix is singular, when using the Moore-Penrose generalized inverse matrix?

Tags: statistics, regression, matrix-rank, pseudoinverse

The OLS estimators is

[image]

But if $Y$ is a $50 \times 1$ matrix, and the design matrix $X$ is $50 \times 16$.

The design matrix $X^T X$ is singular, then what will the estimate coefficient function be, when using  the Moore-Penrose generalized inverse matrix?

Is the function still the same, but just have to replace the inverse matrix of $X^T X$ into the Moore-Penrose generalized inverse matrix of $X^T X$?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The case when $X^T X$ is singular is usually called [multicollinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity). There are several standart ways to deal with it:

1. You can just get rid of the strongly correlated features.
2. You can use regularization ($l_{1}$ or $l_{2}$ is a common choice: in case of $l_{2}$ regularization the formula for betas will be: $\hat \beta = (X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1}X^T y, \ $ where $I$ is identity matrix.)
3. You can use [principal components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis), as they are always uncorrelated.

Comment: Thank you, but I must use the Moore-Penrose generalized inverse matrix, could you tell me the estimate coefficient function of this, please?

Comment: @abba If you use the pseudoinverse, you should obtain the least-norm solution of the normal equations, i.e., the one closest to the origin using the Euclidean distance. I am not 100% sure. Verify it.